# Can't pass token from gradle.properties to settings.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, mapbox, mapbox-android

I followed the guide at https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/ and everything seems to work except that I can't pick the token stored in `gradle.properties` to authenticate myself on the Mapbox Maven repository in `settings.gradle`.
The methods shown in the installation guide are not working for me.

Here is my `settings.gradle`:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
            credentials {
                // Do not change the username below.
                // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username).
                username = "mapbox"
                // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
                password = System.getenv("MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN")
            }
        }
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
}
rootProject.name = "MyApp Name"
include ':app'
```

And here is my `gradle.properties`:

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.
# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.
# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
# AndroidX package structure to make it clearer which packages are bundled with the
# Android operating system, and which are packaged with your app"s APK
# https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn
android.useAndroidX=true
# Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX
android.enableJetifier=true
MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN=this_is_my_secret_access_token
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading gradle docs, I found out that the thing which the mapbox installation guide is doing wrong is setting the token variable in `gradle.properties`.
You need to specify it as a system property (see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_system_properties), so essentially all you have to do is to change

```
MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN=this_is_my_secret_access_token
```

in

```
systemProp.MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN=this_is_my_secret_access_token
```

Now move to the `settings.gradle` file and change the line

```
password = System.getenv("MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN")
```

with

```
password = System.properties["MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN"]
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer, I have same problem and it solved

Comment: @OneDev I am glad to have been helpful!